# Images not enlarging on click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image

In my page I have a large image and set of small unit images. the large image will be loaded on page load. but when i click on small images it will get enlarge and get displayed in place of large image. the small images are displaying on page . but it has no effect on clicking them

here is my code

```
    <div class="invDetailImage">
         <img id="imgenlarge" src="" runat="server" alt="" align="middle" style="max-height:380px; max-width:579px; vertical-align:middle;"/>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblerr"  Visible="false"  style="max-height:380px; max-width:579px; vertical-align:middle;font-size:large;"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <!-- SMALL IMAGES -->
    <div class="invDetailPhotoBox" runat="server" id="photobox"> 
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblphotos" Text="Select a photo below to view in the window above:"></asp:Label><br />
       <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrinventoryphotos"  onitemdatabound="rptrinventoryphotos_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <img id="imgInventory" src="" runat="server" alt='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' style="display:none;"  />
                 <div onclick="large('<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>')" style="float:left;clear:none; margin-left:-12px;">
                  <asp:Image ID="Image1" Visible="true"  runat="server" />
                 </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> function large(src) { 
var str=src; document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imgenlarge").src = (str); 
} 

function loading(img) { img.src = "images/loading.gif"; } 
</script>

     protected void rptrinventoryphotos_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
     {
        HtmlImage img1 =(HtmlImage) e.Item.FindControl("imgInventory");
        Image img = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image1");
        img.ImageUrl = "http://localhost:22525/DWLive/ImageResizeHandler.ashx?imgPath=" + img1.Alt + "&width=75&height=56";

        img.Style.Add("margin-left", "-12px");
        img.Style.Add("background-image", "url('images/loading9.gif')");
        img.Style.Add("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
        img.Style.Add("background-position", "center left");
        //img.Attributes.Add("onclick", "large('" + img1.Alt + "')");
        string[] a = img1.Alt.Split((@"/").ToCharArray());
      }
```

can anyone help please? thanks.

Comment: Where is the code for your JavaScript `large()` function?

Comment: @TimBJames it is there in the code

Comment: If you have found the solution to your question then post it as the answer and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @TimBJames but now i have a doubt. how to show loading image while image loads in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in JavaScript. I changed it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function large(link) { 
        var str = link;
    }

    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imgenlarge").src = (str);
```